# Decoding char to UTF8 in C after 3DES decryption

Tags: c, encryption, padding, 3des

I need some help decoding a char in C to its UTF8 interpretation.

My code so far works this way:

- A `char` is initialised with hexadecimal representation of 'password' `70617373776F7264`
- It is then encrypted using 3DES `DD201F609E49C0609FABA4C8AAFBB1E5`
- Then it is decrypted successfully using 3DES `70617373776F72640808080808080808`

In the`printf("decrypted: %s",dec)` statement, all looks fine and it is displayed as `decrypted: password`

However when doing a string compare, it does not match. Looking closely at the char, I can see that it comes out as `\001password\010\010\010\010\010\010\010\010` (this is due to the padding)

Is there any way to either un-pad or to decode to *UTF8*? [something similar to this](http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/cgi/unicode-decoder/utf8-decoder)

Edit with code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <openssl/des.h>
#include <openssl/rand.h>
#include <ldap.h>
#include "k.h"
#include "hex.h"


#define ULONG unsigned long
#define INT unsigned int


char *encrypt(char *data)
{

  int i = 0;
  int len = 0;
  int nlen = 0;


  char *key1 = "1313232323231313";
  char *key2 = "6789678967896789";
  char *key3 = "1313232323231313";

  /* Padding */
  char ch = '\0';
  unsigned char out[64] = {0};
  unsigned char src[64] = {0};


  unsigned char *ptr  = NULL;
  unsigned char block[8] = {0};
  DES_key_schedule ks1, ks2, ks3;

  /* set password table */
  ptr = hex2bin(key1, strlen(key1), &nlen);
  memcpy(block, ptr, sizeof(block));
  free(ptr);
  DES_set_key_unchecked((C_Block *)block, &ks1);

  ptr = hex2bin(key2, strlen(key2), &nlen);
  memcpy(block, ptr, sizeof(block));
  free(ptr);
  DES_set_key_unchecked((C_Block *)block, &ks2);

  ptr = hex2bin(key3, strlen(key3), &nlen);
  memcpy(block, ptr, sizeof(block));
  free(ptr);
  DES_set_key_unchecked((C_Block *)block, &ks3);

  ptr = hex2bin(data, strlen(data), &nlen);
  memcpy(src, ptr, nlen);
  free(ptr);

  len = (nlen / 8 + (nlen % 8 ? 1: 0)) * 8;

  ch = 8 - nlen % 8;
  memset(src + nlen, ch, (8 - nlen % 8) % 8);

  printf("Raw data: ");
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      printf("%02X", *(src + i));
  }
  printf("\n");

  for (i = 0; i < len; i += 8) {
      DES_ecb3_encrypt((C_Block *)(src + i), (C_Block *)(out + i), &ks1, &ks2, &ks3, DES_ENCRYPT);
  }

  printf("Encrypted: ");
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      printf("%02X" , *(out + i));
  }
  printf("\n");


  return out;

}


char *decrypt(char *data)
{

  int i = 0;
  int len = 0;
  int nlen = 0;


  char *key1 = "1313232323231313";
  char *key2 = "6789678967896789";
  char *key3 = "1313232323231313";

  /* Padding */
  int ch = 0;
  unsigned char out[64] = {0};
  unsigned char src[64] = {0};


  unsigned char *ptr  = NULL;
  unsigned char block[8] = {0};
  DES_key_schedule ks1, ks2, ks3;

  /* set password table */
  ptr = hex2bin(key1, strlen(key1), &nlen);
  memcpy(block, ptr, sizeof(block));
  free(ptr);
  DES_set_key_unchecked((C_Block *)block, &ks1);

  ptr = hex2bin(key2, strlen(key2), &nlen);
  memcpy(block, ptr, sizeof(block));
  free(ptr);
  DES_set_key_unchecked((C_Block *)block, &ks2);

  ptr = hex2bin(key3, strlen(key3), &nlen);
  memcpy(block, ptr, sizeof(block));
  free(ptr);
  DES_set_key_unchecked((C_Block *)block, &ks3);

  ptr = hex2bin(data, strlen(data), &nlen);
  memcpy(src, ptr, nlen);
  free(ptr);

  len = (nlen / 8 + (nlen % 8 ? 1: 0)) * 8;

  ch = 8 - nlen % 8;
  memset(src + nlen, ch, (8 - nlen % 8) % 8);

  printf("Raw data: ");
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      printf("%02X", *(src + i));
  }
  printf("\n");

  for (i = 0; i < len; i += 8) {
      DES_ecb3_encrypt((C_Block *)(src + i), (C_Block *)(out + i), &ks1, &ks2, &ks3, DES_DECRYPT);
  }

  printf("Decrypted: ");
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      printf("%02X", *(out + i));
  }

  printf("\n");
  return out;

}


K DES_ecb3_do(K user, K pass,K fl )
{
  int res = 0;
  int flag = fl->i;
  char *usn = user->s;

  char *enc = pass->s;
  char *decr = "";
  char dec[32];

  if(flag==1)
  {
    decr = encrypt(enc);
    strcat(dec,decr);
  }
  else if(flag==0)
  {
    decr = decrypt(enc);
    strcat(dec,decr);
  }
  int ret;
  ret = strcmp(dec, "password");
  if(ret==0)
  {
    printf("they match");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("they don't match\n");
    return (K) 0;
  }  
 printf("decrypted pass is:%s\n",dec);

   return ks(dec);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand is unpadding and decoding UTF-8 equivalent in this case? And if so, why? Also, can you please post the code? It might be for some other reason like a buffer overflow or anything that can invoke undefined behavior or cause data corruption.

Comment: If `printf` output is fine, how could `strcmp` fails? Post your code.

Comment: @LPs Because the decoded string begins with `'\001'`, which isn't visible in `printf()`'s output but of course seen by `strcmp()`.

Comment: As I wrote. Post your code, with actual infos we cannot help you. I can only guess that is your decode function that put that "garbage" in your output string.

Comment: @LPs I've edited my post with the code. For the last bit, this is because it is compiled as a library and then called from within a 'q' process

Comment: I fail to see what this has to do with UTF-8. Character encoding != cryptographic encoding. For a cryptographic function, a "string" is just a sequence of bytes.

Comment: @iharob I want to retrieve password because the way it works is that I would receive an encrypted password from a C# service, decrypt it and then do an AD authentication using LDAP

Comment: Has `hex2bin` a malloc in its code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `decrypt` function you return the result of decryption from a local variable, that is out of scope in the caller.

Change `out[64]` to `static` or as global, or `malloc` it.

Finally your code invoke [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because of you are returning an address of stack area.

**EDIT after OP comment request**

Your code is

```
char *decrypt(char *data)
{

  int i = 0;
  int len = 0;
  int nlen = 0;


  char *key1 = "1313232323231313";
  char *key2 = "6789678967896789";
  char *key3 = "1313232323231313";

  /* Padding */
  int ch = 0;
  unsigned char out[64] = {0};
  unsigned char src[64] = {0};

  // stuff....
 return out;
}
```

This code is declaring out array as local, otherwise stack allocated. That the variable is available only in local scope: inside `decrypt` function.

This means that when the function return to the caller function `DES_ecb3_do` a memory address that could be corrupted. You should not access that address.

To solve the problem you must make `out` variable available out of `decrypt` function scope using, for example, one of the following:

1) you define the `out` as `global`:

```
unsigned char out[64] = {0};

char *decrypt(char *data)
{
   // STUFF
}
```

2) You define `out` as `static` inside your function:

```
char *decrypt(char *data)
{
   static unsigned char out[64] = {0};
   // STUFF
}
```

3) You define `out` as a poiter and `malloc` it:

```
char *decrypt(char *data)
{
   unsigned char *out] = malloc(64);
   // STUFF
}
```

Hope it is clear enough.

Comment: Can you give an example of what it would like, I fail to see how I should do it, I am a bit of a C newbie

Comment: Thank you, I finally used the option 2)
Also I fixed the issue with the leading character `\001`, I was wrongly using strcat instead of strcpy

Comment: @kompsci `strcat` was wrong, but `strcpy` is useless. You can directely compare with `ret = strcmp(dec, "password");`

Comment: agreed, I've changed it now

Answer (score 0):

Is it because your decrypted string is not NULL terminated?
Also if your "string comparison" is 
    if(dec == "password")
Then that's not going to work, try 
    if (strcmp(dec, "password") == 0)